# tflite inferencing is crashing because tensors memory is not accessible

Tags: tensorflow, tflite

I have quite strange issue with inferencing of my tflite model.
After loading model - i call AllocateTensors() on interpretor.
I call it only once in this place, because according to documentation this function is quite expensive.
After calling this function - i checked all tensors (over 350) memory pointers. All the pointers are correct and accessible.

But... when during inferencing - it crashes immediately, because it turned out - all tensors pointers become inaccessible. Like if they freed for some reason.
I checked the code - I don't do any operations on interpreter between model loading and inferencing invoking.
So looks like some garbage collector destroys the tensors memory.

Input tensors are still accessible and have allocation type: kTfLiteArenaRw.
But intermediate sensors all destroyed and have allocation type: kTfLiteMmapRo.

How to prevent memory destroyng betwee building interpreter and starting Invoke ?
I cannot afford allocating tensors each frame.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind,

I fixed the issue.

Problem was in model flat buffer which was unique ptr on stack and destroyed when i left the function.

Looks like i cannot destroy the model while interpreter is alive...